# when i performing quality check in Jenkins through sonarqube facing below bug

Tags: sonarqube

when i performing quality check in Jenkins through sonarqube facing below bug [image]

Comment: It's important to know what version of Java is being used in the shell in Jenkins to run the "mvn "command, and it probably would be useful to know what version "mvn" you have. In recent versions of SonarQube, the SonarQube scanner requires at least Java 11 to run.